# Spring Data JPA - Update Whole object

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an object that may have one or more fields updated, is there a way to update all fields in the database from that object using JPA repository queries? Or do I need to specify every field that needs updated?

Comment: You can do one thing is that , get the all data from unique field in an object and just **set** your new updated field in this object and just save/update that object.Click here [link](http://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/updating-entities-with-update-query-spring-data-jpa).

Comment: The example on the link specifies fields that are to be update, I'm looking for what would be equivalent to just persisting the current objects state. In Hibernate I would just do obj.persist() but I don't know if that's possible in JPA repo.

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was that the JPA CRUD repo save function automatically handles update versus insert:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java

However, my issue was I was creating a new entity from my DTO data and the repo thought it needed to insert.